# Definning a reference to method attribute for custom view

Tags: android

I want my custom view to have an attribute that can be set via XML that defines a callback for some custom behaviour that this view would support.

I know that i can tweak a simple string to be such using reflections, but it exists in the android API as Button has android:onClick so i wonder if this is something i can get out of the box instead of reinventing the wheel.

Anyone familiar with how it is done or do i must go ahead and implement it on my own using refelections?

Answer (score 0):

seeing the [android source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.%3Cinit%3E%28android.content.Context%2Candroid.util.AttributeSet%2Cint%2Cint%29), looks as they did the same as i was going to :

```
case R.styleable.View_onClick:
 if (context.isRestricted()) {
     throw new IllegalStateException("The android:onClick attribute cannot "
             + "be used within a restricted context");
 }

 final String handlerName = a.getString(attr);
 if (handlerName != null) {
     setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         private Method mHandler;

         public void More ...onClick(View v) {
             if (mHandler == null) {
                 try {
                     mHandler = getContext().getClass().getMethod(handlerName,
                             View.class);
                 } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                     int id = getId();
                     String idText = id == NO_ID ? "" : " with id '"
                             + getContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(
                                 id) + "'";
                     throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find a method " +
                             handlerName + "(View) in the activity "
                             + getContext().getClass() + " for onClick handler"
                             + " on view " + View.this.getClass() + idText, e);
                 }
             }

             try {
                 mHandler.invoke(getContext(), View.this);
             } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                 throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute non "
                         + "public method of the activity", e);
             } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                 throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute "
                         + "method of the activity", e);
             }
         }
     });
 }
```

So this i guess is the only way...